# matplotlib pyplot graph starts from x0 y0

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot one array like this:

https://i.imgur.com/xuJNbu9.png

but the result is something like this:

https://i.imgur.com/g1LhL7e.png

Why are the lines going from x0 y0 at the start and end of the graph?

```
        pyplot.figure(num=None, figsize=(20, 20), dpi=100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
        pyplot.subplot(2, 1, 1)
        pyplot.plot(graph_values[0], graph_values[1])
        pyplot.xlabel("time [s]")
        pyplot.ylabel("signal1 [mps]")

        pyplot.subplot(2, 1, 2)
        pyplot.plot(graph_values[0], graph_values[2])
        pyplot.xlabel("time [s]")
        pyplot.ylabel("signal2 [deg/sec]")

        figureFilename = "graph_" + file.split(".")[0] + ".jpeg"
        pyplot.savefig(figureFilename)
```

where graph_values is created as:

```
    nrows = 3
    ncols = len(signal)
    graph_values = zeros((nrows, ncols))
```

and only the necessary indexes have values replaced, the rest remain 0.

I'm expecting the graph to just show the "lines" where you got values and that's it, empty before and after. These diagonal lines from x0 y0 don't make sense and i cannot find anything that could solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post your complete code? Right now it looks like you are trying to plot a bunch of zeros...

Comment: *"only the necessary indexes have values replaced, the rest remain 0."* This means that some of your data ***are*** 0, and hence you see that line from/to 0. Make sure not to plot 0 values, if you don't wan't them to be part of your visualization.

Comment: I either expect a line that goes from X0 to X1922 and then at X1923 it starts from that value in array.

Or only show values that are not 0.

But not this diagonal lines.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that by doing

```
 pyplot.plot(graph_values[0], graph_values[1])
```

I would force x axis with values from graph_values[0]
But changing to

```
pyplot.plot(graph_values[1])
```

seemed to work because x axis is taken cared of by the original length of the array when i did

```
    ncols = len(signal)
    graph_values = zeros((nrows, ncols))
```